# What is the difference between Facebook for Websites and Facebook SDK?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

What is the difference between Facebook for Websites and Facebook SDK?

I see the two referenced all the time, and it's confusing.

My setup is a client side javascript app and am wondering which I should use.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook for websites is made to enable some facebook features on your website, such as the like button. It also allows you to use facebook login and registration for your website much like open id. This eliminates the need for your own user login and registration scripts. It also allows you to use the graph API, giving you access the full social graph of a given user.

Facebook Javascript SDK gives you access to the graph API and a lot more, like facebook dialogs and REST API. Further, it provides a mechanism for rendering of the XFBML versions of our Social Plugins, and a way for Canvas pages to communicate with Facebook.

I think you should consider using the Facebook Javascript SDK as it offers you much more functionality.

Comment: So facebook SDK is a superset of FB for websites?

Answer (score 1):

SDK stands for software development kit. It's a toolset for doing certain actions.

In terms of Facebook SDK there are official toolsets for

- PHP
- iOS
- Android
- JavaScript

These toolsets make it easier for developers to interact with Facebook API (Application Programming Interface), which is a way in which Facebook allows developers to interact with some of its data.

*Facebook for Websites* represents the *idea* of making your site a social interaction with respect to Facebook and driving growth through these social interactions. This can be in the form of SDKs (the toolsets mentioned before) or plugins.

Utilizing the *Facebook Platform* (which encompasses all the toolsets, plugins and API) you can make a better more sociable experience for your website. And that's what *Facebook for Websites* represents.

---

So you have a client side Javascript app utilizing the JS *SDK* (this is the toolset). Now this could be an app for your website in which case you are trying to enrich the experience or you are just making an app for others to enrich their sites/pages with your app.

- App for your website? You are using the SDK and it is going on the idea of *Facebook for Websites*
- Apps for distribution to other websites/pages? You are using the SDK for giving them the chance to use *Facebook for their Website*

So *Facebook for Websites* denotes the loose phrase of using the *Platform* on a website for a richer social experience.

I suggest you read this page even if you don't get everything it will give you a better idea than you already had

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/